# Display the UILabel verticallly from the NSMutableArray inside the UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a list of array objects which I pass into to a loop and display it as `UILabel` dynamically. However I need the values to display it in a vertical. Below are my code,

```
 labelArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"One”, @“Two”, @“Three",@"four",@"five",@"six" ,nil];

//inside a method with a loop am passing the array and creating the labels.
-(void) createlabel:(CGRect) frame{
  float xCoordinate = frame.origin.x;
  float yCoordinate = frame.origin.y;
  int labelHeight =30;
  int gapBetweenTwoLabels =2;
  int labelWidth = 100;
  for(int counter = 0; counter < [labelArrays count]; counter++){
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoordinate,yCoordinate,labelWidth,labelHeight)];
  label.text = [labelArrays objectAtIndex:counter];
  [self addSubview:label];
  xCoordinate = xCoordinate + labelWidth + gapBetweenTwoLabels;
 }
}
//frame
[self createlabel:CGRectMake(25,130,100,40)];
```

This displays me as

```
one two three four five six
```

but i need it as

```
one two three
four five six
```

can anyone suggest me how can i achieve it? Note: I use this method inside the UIView not in the controller.

Comment: You have to change the `yCoordinate`.

Comment: @Larme I tried varying the `yCoordinate` but cannot display the array values in next line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your y-coordinate as @Larme mentioned

```
labelArrays = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"One”, @“Two”, @“Three", @"four", @"five", @"six" ,nil];
```

If you want output as following

> one 
>   two 
>   three 
>   four 
>   five 
>   six

```
-(void) createlabel:(CGRect) frame {
    CGFloat xCoordinate = frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat yCoordinate = frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat labelHeight = frame.size.height;
    CGFloat labelWidth = frame.size.width;
    CGFloat gapBetweenTwoLabels = 2;

    for(int counter = 0; counter < [labelArrays count]; counter++) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame : CGRectMake(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, labelWidth, labelHeight)];
        label.text = [labelArrays objectAtIndex:counter];
        [self addSubview:label];
        yCoordinate = yCoordinate + labelHeight + gapBetweenTwoLabels;
    }
}
```

But if you want output as :

> one
>   two
>   three 
>   four
>   five
>   six

```
-(void) createlabel:(CGRect) frame {
    CGFloat xCoordinate = frame.origin.x;
    CGFloat yCoordinate = frame.origin.y;
    CGFloat labelHeight = frame.size.height;
    CGFloat labelWidth = frame.size.width;
    CGFloat gapBetweenTwoLabels = 2;

    for(int counter = 0; counter < [labelArrays count]; counter++) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame : CGRectMake(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, labelWidth, labelHeight)];
        label.text = [labelArrays objectAtIndex:counter];
        [self addSubview:label];
        if((counter+1)%3 == 0) {
            xCoordinate = 0;
            yCoordinate = yCoordinate + labelHeight + gapBetweenTwoLabels;
        } else {
            xCoordinate = xCoordinate + labelWidth + gapBetweenTwoLabels;
        }
    }
}
```

Function call

```
[self createlabel:CGRectMake(25,130,100,40)];
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried with the second way you mentioned but getting the output as "one" in the first line and "two", "three", "four" in the second line and finally "five" and "six" in the third line. I tired adjusting the coordinate points its not working. The first line contains only "one".

Comment: @Sabarish, check now, actually it was logical mistake, I have not tested in machine

Comment: @Sabarish, happy to help you.